# Can old motherboard with Pentium E2140 in it now support Pentium E6600?

Tags: cpu

Can old motherboard with Pentium E2140 in it now support Pentium E6600? Here is the [Specifications](http://ark.intel.com/compare/29738,42807) of the 2 processors on Intel site.

E6600 is really cheap and can benefit performance a lot (more than doubling I believe).  They have the same socket but I'm not sure if E6600 will work on the old motherboard.

It's not easy for me to learn what motherboard it is. (I do not own that computer I want to upgrade.  Actually, it was for a relative, who supported me learning programming by providing me a computer a decade ago, which lead to my being a CS-major university student now.  I received my first salary as an intern recently and want to give her a gift.  A CPU today is nowhere near the value of a computer a decade ago, but that's what I can afford as a student at the moment.)

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the motherboard make and model it's not possible to tell for sure.

The BIOS needs to recognise the processor to initialise it correctly, so it comes down to whether your motherboard manufacturer has provided a BIOS update that supports the newer chip.

Answer (score 0):

Should work fine. You might have to flash your BIOS if it's really old.